# Loop an array of strings to be use for element ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I loop an array of strings to be use for element ID?

Given the code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  var IDs = ['ID1', 'ID2']
  for(var x=0; x < IDs.length; x++) {
    const thisID = document.getElementById(IDs[x])
    thisID.style.opacity = '0'
  }
}
```

Am I doing it right or I might be missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Whats is your problem?

Comment: You'll want to apply ids or styles by id in the returned jsx of the component. You don't want to be manually altering the DOM in React.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react`, You have to do similar to this,

```
export default function App() {
  const elements = [
    { id: 1001, label: "Orange" },
    { id: 1002, label: "Apple" },
    { id: 1003, label: "Banana" }
  ];
  const selectedDiv = [1001];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List</h1>
      {elements.map((v) => (
        <div style={{ opacity: selectedDiv.includes(v.id) ? "0" : "1" }}>
          {v.label}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-brook-buyyl?file=/src/App.js:51-464

Answer (score 0):

You provided little information. Maybe it will help

```js
let IDs = ['ID1', 'ID2'];

IDs.forEach(function(number) {
    console.log(number);
  let div = document.getElementById(number); //javascript
  // or use jquery 
  // const thisID = $(`#{number}`) //jquery 
  div.style.opacity = '0';
});

// or use jQuery 

let IDjQuery = ['ID4', 'ID5'];

IDjQuery.forEach(function(number) {
  console.log(number);
  let divjQuery = $(`#${number}`); //jQuery 
  divjQuery.css('opacity', '0');
});
```

```html
<div id="ID1">Test 1</div>
<div id="ID2">Test 2</div>
<div id="ID3">Test 3</div>
<!-- or use jQuery  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ID4">Test 4</div>
<div id="ID5">Test 5</div>
<div id="ID6">Test 6</div>
```